# Behavior in scalaz not understood

Tags: scala, scalaz

A question from a ScalaZ neophite here.
I don't quite understand how the:

```
1.some
```

or the disjunction related:

```
"Success!".right
```

work.
I am not able to find any implicit conversions that will allow the behavior above.
I know how to use them but I am interested in their implementation.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class containing the method `some` is `OptionIdOps`

```
final class OptionIdOps[A](self: A) {
  def some: Option[A] = Some(self)
}
```

If you look inside the definition, you'll see an additional implicit available for any type `A` to `OptionIdOps` inside a trait definition:

```
trait ToOptionIdOps {
  implicit def ToOptionIdOps[A](a: A) = new OptionIdOps(a)
}
```

So de-facto, the compiler does:

```
val someOfInt = new OptionIdOps(1).some
```

Comment: thanks Yuval, as usual your answers are very informative